# Howto : Index=LastIndex+6

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I have designed a script to put data that matches a particular string.  There are hundreds of thousands of machine names in the text file.  Now that I have all the data, I need to go through this list and somehow setup something takes something like  Idex=LastIndex+6. If the two rows equal six, I would like to export the computer names and place them in 2 rows in a different csv/excel file in two separate columns.  If the difference between the two number is not 6, then ignore it.

Here is the code I have now to gather the info.  I just don't know how to do the count.

```
$Servers = Get-Content c:\temp\dad\servers.txt

foreach ($Server in $servers)
{


    Get-ChildItem -Path \\$server\image_store$\Win764\DADLOGS -recurse -Filter ADReport.ini | Get-Content | Select-String -CaseSensitive -pattern "\bName=\b" |
    Export-Csv c:\scripts\test.csv -Force -Append -NoTypeInformation
    $intRow = $intRow + 1
}
```

Here are the results I get :  Some have a count of 6 until the next number in the file, but others will not.

110 Name=042LOAN-TPL-Y

161 Name=052SHARE-TPL-K

212 Name=052SHARE-TPL-ZZ

258 Name=NYCMTENTESTING

38559   Name=gert34t-TPD-Z

38604   Name=njytyety-XPU

38610   Name=jnrthe-TPL-AD

38655   Name=dger54-XPU

38661   Name=ertydffj-TPL-AE

38706   Name=5erteefg-XPU

38712   Name=nfhjtre-TPL-AG

Comment: My question would be; "say what now?"

Comment: Of that list what is the desired output? Do you only want the items that are Index=LastIndex+6? Do you want it split into two files? Do you want one file with all records, and another file with just the +-6 records?

Comment: Your question is very confusing. Can you provide examples with sample data? It's not clear what you mean by "Some have a count of 6 until the next number in the file, but others will not" or "if there is a record on 1000 and if the next value is 6 higher than the previous (1006)", or how any of that relates to your code (I don't see anything in the code that checks for a difference of 6). Please read [this advice on asking good questions](http://goo.gl/1tBMnR). **Pay special attention to the "Golden Rule"**. You know what you're referring to, but readers only know what your words actually say.

Comment: THE Mad Technician has the idea.  The only records i want to keep are the ones that have  Index=LastIndex+6.  If you look above, 38502 and 38508 have exactly 6 as a difference. I would like to take that set and place it in a new file in to different columns.  38604 and 38610 also have 6 in between.  That set would be good.  38655 and 38661.  The top ones do not match as the index=lastindex + 6 does not match.  161 - 110 does not equal 6

Comment: I think it would be easier for people to understand if you could clearly state **why** this needs to be done. On the surface, it reads like an academic exercise.

Comment: We upgraded or replaced 1000's of machines from XP to Windows 7. For each machine there is log file for the migration process.  If we actually used the same machine and just re-imaged it, there would be two NAME= references which are exactly 6 lines apart in the log file.  That is what I am trying to get seperated out.  I need to make sure that the old machine name is disabled in Active Directory.  Does this make sense?  The easy part of gathering the info from 100's of servers is completed.  That is what I have now, that produces the data above.

Comment: You could also just wait 30 days or so and check for computer accounts with an old lastLogonTimestamp attribute (e.g., using [oldcmp.exe](http://www.joeware.net/freetools/tools/oldcmp/)) and delete them.

Comment: This is not computers 101.  I think I know that Bill.  You obviously don't know the DAD process.

Comment: Just suggesting a path from point A to B that's less friction...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, I think this might be at least part of a solution:

```
$Data = 
(@'
110 Name=042LOAN-TPL-Y
161 Name=052SHARE-TPL-K
212 Name=052SHARE-TPL-ZZ
258 Name=NYCMTENTESTING
38559 Name=gert34t-TPD-Z
38604 Name=njytyety-XPU
38610 Name=jnrthe-TPL-AD
38655 Name=dger54-XPU
38661 Name=ertydffj-TPL-AE
38706 Name=5erteefg-XPU
38712 Name=nfhjtre-TPL-AG
'@).split("`n") |
foreach {$_.trim()}

$Last = '0'

$Keep = 
$Data | 
 foreach {

   if ( 6 -eq $_.split()[0] - $last.split()[0]  )
     { 
       ,($Last.split()[1],$_.split()[1] -replace 'Name=')
       $last ='0'
     }

    else { $last = $_ }
  }
```

$keep will be an array of arrays, with two computer names in each second-level array.

Same basic idea, adapted for import/export csv (not tested):

```
$InputFile = 'c:\somedir\somefile.csv'
$OutputFile = 'c:\somedir\clean.csv'

$NullRecord =  '' | Select Index,ComputerName 
$Last = $NullRecord.psobject.copy()

Import-Csv $InputFile |

 foreach {

   if ( 6 -eq $_.Index - $last.Index  )
     { 
       New-Object PSObject -Property @{
            OldMachine = $Last.ComputerName -replace 'Name='
            NewMachine = $_.ComputerName -replace 'Name='
           }

       $Last = $NullRecord.psobject.copy()
     }

    else { $Last = $_.psobject.copy() }

 } | Export-Csv $OutputFile -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: When I run this script I get this error. ERROR: ForEach-Object : Cannot bind parameter 'Process'. Cannot convert the "" value of type "System.String" to type "System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock".
Dad_Pull_V2.ps1 (33): ERROR: At Line: 33 char: 1

Comment: I'm not sure how you're getting that error on line 33.  The whole thing is only 30 lines.....

Comment: My Fault.  If I run your code from a PS console, it works perfectly, yet if I copy and paste the code in my program and run it from console, it prompts me for : cmdlet ForEach-Object at command pipeline position 1  
Supply values for the following parameters:           
Process[0]:

Comment: This produces the exact info I need MJolinor!  I would like though to import the data from a comma delimited text file that has 2 fields. Index and ComputerName.  If the results could be exported to a new csv file called clean.csv with the matching machines side by side. Example  OldMachine, NewMachine where the first of the pair that you clean up is always the old one.  Hope this makes sense.

Comment: I thinks so. Added another version to the answer.  See if that works.

Comment: Don't use that.  I just realized it's not going to work. I'll update when I get it sorted out.

Comment: Okay, fixed (I think).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55625/discussion-between-kent-and-mjolinor).

Comment: As usual mjolinor, you were spot on!  Thanks for the excellent mentoring.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do what you're asking, but it may not give you the best possible performance.

```
$Servers = Get-Content c:\temp\dad\servers.txt

$indexes = @()
$matches = @()

$Servers | % {
    $currentIndex = $_.Split(" ")[0]
    if ($currentIndex-6 -in $indexes) {
        $matches += $currentIndex-6
        $matches += $currentIndex
        }
    $indexes += $currentIndex
    }

"`"Index`", `"Name`"" | Out-File c:\scripts\test.csv -Force
$Servers | % {
    $currentIndex = $_.Split(" ")[0]
    if ($currentIndex -in $matches) {
        "$currentIndex, `"$name`"" | Out-File c:\scripts\test.csv -Force -Append
        }
    }
```

This is assuming you want to log both the old and new computers, but you could modify that pretty easily by removing one of the `$matches += ...` lines.

Comment: I screwed up Tim.   This is where I would import the info in to the array
    $Servers = Import-Csv -Path C:\scripts\test.csv

Comment: Uh, so what's the example data you gave? There aren't any commas...? Do you mean `Export-Csv`?

Comment: Can you also give an example of what you want the output to look like?

Comment: The file for import has two fields that are comma delimited.  Index and Computer_Name are the labels and the data looks looks like the data that I have in the results above.  I would like the final product to strip out the machines that don't have a value of 6 in between and put the good ones (The pairs) in a new csv file with two fields Old_Machine and New_Machine.  Hope this makes sense.